# How do I avoid CORS error for flask api?

Tags: python, api, flask, cors

The following is my code

```
@app.route('/<string:article_id>/<int:n>', methods=['GET'])
def get_similar(article_id,n):   
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=['article','similar'])
    df['article']=df.article.str.replace('.txt ?','')
    df['similar']=df.similar.str.replace('.txt ?','')
    if n<df.article.nunique():
        if any(df.article==article_id):
            df5=df[df['article'].isin([article_id])]
            df5=df5.similar   
            df5=df5[0:int(n)]
            df5.index=range(int(n)) 
            x=df5.to_json(orient='columns')
            data = {}
            data['success'] = 'true'
            y= json.dumps(data)
            res = json.loads(y)
            res['data'] = json.loads(x)
            res_str = json.dumps(res, sort_keys=True)
            return (res_str)
        else:
            data = {}
            data['success'] = 'false'
            json_data = json.dumps(data)
            return json_data
    else:
        data = {}
        data['success'] = 'false'
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return json_data
```

I'm getting the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://107.20.3.77:8286/919/5. Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8001' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can someone help me avoid this error. When I try curl it's working but in front end it's not working.

Comment: Checkout the Flask-CORS extension: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Tried this still gets the same error

Comment: I recommend you to use jsonify function to return json data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this decorator.

```
from flask import current_app, make_response, request
from functools import wraps, update_wrapper

def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
            max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
            automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
               resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

Then you can declare routes like this

```
@app.route('/api/v1/user', methods=['OPTIONS', 'POST'])
@crossdomain(origin="*")
def add_user():
    pass
```

Source : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/